# Where is the "per file" Custom Build Step in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have converted my C++ project from Visual Studio 2010 to the 2013 Community edition.

With previous versions I could always right click on a source file and edit a Custom Build step in the properties. Now I can't find the equivalent in VS2013.

The converted project has a Custom Build Step and runs it, but where do I edit it ?

When I open the raw 2013 .vcxproj file, I can see my custom build step as

```
<CustomBuild Include="foo.h.in">
...
</CustomBuild>
```

But I don't really want to keep editing my project with a text editor...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as [harper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266487/harper) described. One more thing to add - in VS 2013 and higher they renamed file specific `Custom Build Step` to `Custom Build Tool` and its not shown by default. To show it change the `Configuration Properties` -> `General` -> `Item Type` to **Custom Build Tool**. Apply the changes and 'Custom Build Tool' sub menu will appear.

Answer (score 1):

You find it in the project property pages. Navigate to `Configuration Properties` -> `Custom Build Step` -> `General`.

I had sometimes strange results when converting old projects. I use to create new projects and add the files nowadays what gives better results.

Comment: That seems to be a "per project" custom build step, not explicitely for one file and it doesn't show the build step I had defined in my old project.

Comment: It is for one file if you set it by right-clicking on the file in Solution Explorer, then picking "Properties" from the pop-up menu.  That's how you set single-file project properties.

Comment: @librik: Thats how I used to set it in previous versions, but in VS 2013 Community, I don't see a Custom Build Step in the per file properties.